# Can't run xunit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, xunit.net

I have vs 2012, xUnit.net and xUnit runner for vs 2012. I see all my tests. But they are always into "Not run tests" section. Yesterday they were working, but today.. I don't know. I've reverted all changes. Tests into "Not run tests"  section again. Do you have ideas?

Comment: Is this your problem? https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/2

Comment: No. I decided to use resharper xUnit runner. It's not so fast but it's working.

Comment: We just shipped 0.99.7 this morning. Please give it a try, and if things aren't fixed, open an issue. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099 https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit